# Issue loading in different assemblies to Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, csom, sharepoint-online

I've been trying to load in assemblies to powershell for sharepoint and most of them work fine like the ones below:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

But when I try and add in ones with a different file path:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll"
```

I get the following error:

> "Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

Can anyone help with this?

-----UPDATE-----

```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
   #Bind to site collection
   $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
   $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
   $Context.Credentials = $Creds

   #Retrieve list
   $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
   $Context.Load($List)
   $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $SPFolder = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder
```

Comment: Silverlight depends on a different version of the CLR (the Silverlight verion of it) as such a assembly that was compiled against that version of the CLR cannot be loaded into a normal CLR program, which Powershell is.

Comment: So is there no way of implementing it then?

Comment: No. What from the Silverlight assemblies do you need that isn't available from the standard Sharepoint Client Object Model?

Comment: I'm trying to implement Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder within my code and the msdn website said that the silverlight assmebly was needed

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.SgarePoint.Client.Folder` is defined [in multiple assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.Aspx), one for each platform that supports this. Given that powershell runs on the Desktop CLR, you'll only need to load the desktop version of the assembly:

> <s>Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight (in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll);</s>
>
> <s>Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Phone (in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Phone.dll)</s>
>
> **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client (in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll)**

You need to pass in the right constructor parameters:

```
 public Folder(
    ClientRuntimeContext context,
    ObjectPath objectPath
 )
```

But I suppose that it's easier to use the following method [(`GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl.Aspx) instead.

Comment: I keep getting the error "Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder."

Comment: Can you share the code snippet by editing your question?

Comment: Yeah I did under Update